# How can I instantiate `T` from inside a `Class<T>` method?

Tags: typescript

Still learning the TypeScriptus.

I'm creating a Model and Collection system for a web app and I need my `Collection` class to be able to instantiate any `Model` subclass as passed when it's constructed, for example: `new Collection<Post>()` would create a list of `Post`s; and `new Collection<Comment>()` would create a list of `Comment`s.

As you will see in the code pasted below I can do the axample as it stands and no error will come from it, but I want to instantiate *any* subclass of `Model` from inside the Collection class not just `Post`. How can I achieve this?

```js
// A Model attributes form API
interface Attr {
    id: number;
    title: string;
}

// Base model class
abstract class Model {
    protected attr: Attr;
    public constructor(attr: Attr) {
        this.attr = attr;
    }
}

// An actual model to be used in the app
class Post extends Model {
    public constructor(attr: Attr) {
        super(attr);
        // other custom stuff, like API adapters, etc.
    }
}

// A collection of Model using type T
class Collection<T extends Model> {
    private collected: T[] = [];

    public async fetch(): Promise<Collection<T>> {
        const attrList: Attr[] = await new Promise<Attr[]>((resolve): void => {
            resolve([{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Post 1'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                title: 'Post 2'
            }] as Attr[]);
        });
        this.collected = attrList.map((attr: Attr): T => {
            // I can instantiate Post from here and cast it,
            // but I want to use whatever is passed in T instead
            return new Post(attr) as T;
        })
        return this;
    }

    public all(): T[] {
        return this.collected;
    }

}

const collection = new Collection<Post>();
const posts: Post[] = collection.all();
```

The key line is the hardcoded instatiation of `Post` inside of `Collection.fetch()` like this: `return new Post(attr) as T;`.

How do you go about instantiating a valid `T` that works, for example, with both `Post` and `Comment` classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Collection<T>` class instances need to hold onto an instance of a constructor for `T`.

Aside: it's probably not a good idea to use the name `Attr` for an interface because there is already [a type in global scope named `Attr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr) which will either be a name collision or a name shadowing, neither of which are particularly pleasant to deal with.  I will change the name to `MyAttr` from here on.

When you construct a `Collection<T>`, you need to pass in a constructor of `T` objects that you can call with a `MyAttr` parameter, and the `Collection<T>` needs to hold onto that constructor to use inside the `fetch()` method implementation.  In Typescript, the type of such a constructor is `new (attr: MyAttr) => T`.  By using a [parameter property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties) we can represent the pass-in-and-hold-onto operation simply:

```
class Collection<T extends Model> {
  private collected: T[] = [];
  public constructor(private ctor: new (attr: MyAttr) => T) {}
```

(If we wanted to write that out, it would be like `private ctor: new (attr: MyAttr) => T; public constructor(ctor: new (attr: MyAttr) => T) { this.ctor = ctor; }`)

Then inside the `fetch()` method we use `this.ctor`:

```
  public async fetch(): Promise<Collection<T>> {
    const attrList = await new Promise<MyAttr[]>(
      (resolve): void => {
        resolve([
          {
            id: 1,
            title: "Post 1"
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            title: "Post 2"
          }
        ]);
      }
    );
    this.collected = attrList.map(attr => new this.ctor(attr));
    return this;
  }
```

And that should work for you.  (Notice I removed your type assertion for the promise resolution... it's not necessary once you fix the name collision with the built-in `Attr` interface)

Finally, when you make `collection`, you pass in the `Post` constructor.  You don't need to manually specify the generic `T` as `Post` anymore, because the compiler will infer that for you:

```
const collection = new Collection(Post);
const posts: Post[] = collection.all();
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CCYxWQbwChllgATALmRAFcBbAI2gG5jkxgwAbCKgZ1ygA5qwC+hQnAYCoiMMgRc4fPmgD2ZCFwJsADlDWQEkMsjg4oVDNlysSumgy7AECtSBk1jaqAApzuFZYFgCUOiQkYAAWwHwAdAF4ALxmFnbI4uKEisqqAApqAsgQAB6QIGSqqBpa4cgOTi5uHrheYD7+FkE2UGFEEch8NLrQnbgh6ZkSOSrIAMJqXDzGwO4APAAqxWUQFVU1XAB8dfrAAG7mKAiLyyZUGwDaALrIKc-pDc6u1y1QbR2nC6QBTtSzUCAAd2QYzB1lCr2OGz6WXsji+Zj46BArhgEDACCivhCVDyBjosQgawWSwgK3WG0Ox36ER+RUSABlYvIUnAIXBOOCoaS1OS+JS4bhnodfGwBr4oBA+IszhBicgzmpyAi6gMSAqlVwVb4HrLdSRmWaBuQqABGAA0pst7E4PCoACICkUbW7HbrRA6nebfWbrcgAEwBwORF28ZAewryMM+qPiJ1PCa+1MRDMDaKxOLXGnGCCmHkWTkCOJ0OC6GHakCQ9gxeLePyJEI5iIKsA0KAgJuxSYSVGNVxwJZE+7PHXIbu9-t5ls3WkmIdZVnyQu3Vb9lINqHU7fuXyesAZjf1BN8EkJ6cpLcrncJCcZoA)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do it.

On my applications I solve (actually, workaround) this by creating a abstract method `getInstance()`:

```
abstract public getInstance(... args): T
```

So on my atual model, I implement this method:

```
public getInstance(...args): Post {
    return new Post(...args);
}
```